# Slick-2D: Change back to default OS cursor

Tags: java, slick2d

I have modified my cursor with

```
cotainer.setMouseCursor(Image image, int hotSpotX, int hotSpotY)
```

How do I change it back to the system default after I've set it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `container.setMouseCursor(org.lwjgl.input.Cursor.CURSOR_8_BIT_ALPHA, int hotSpotX, int hotSpotY);` check if it works, or if it's not exactly what you want..

EDIT: here `container.setDefaultMouseCursor()` [reference](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/GameContainer.html#setDefaultMouseCursor%28%29)

Comment: I want to change it back, after setting it.

Comment: @njallam now have a look, try both the options